# How can I access a variable outside a promise `.then` method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm working on a Spotify app. I'm able to login and get my token. My problem is I cannot access a variable outside the method. In this case `"getCurrentUser"`

This is my method:

```
function getUser() {
  if ($localStorage.token == undefined) {
    throw alert("Not logged in");
  } else {
    Spotify.getCurrentUser().then(function(data) {
      var names = JSON.stringify(data.data.display_name);
      console.log(names)
    })
  }
};
```

As you can see I console.logged the name and I do get the right value in the console. But only works there if I call the function `getUser()` I get `undefined` even with a return of the names variable.

I need to `$scope` that variable.

Comment: I'm guessing you have `return names`, but you also need `return Spotify.getCurrentUser()...` so that it returns the promise (and ultimately the return value from the then)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getUser()` is not returning anything. You need to return the promise from the `Spotify.getCurrentUser()`, and then when you return `names` within *that* it is returned by the outer function.

```
function getUser() {

    if ( $localStorage.token == undefined) {
        throw alert("Not logged in");
    }
    else {
        return Spotify.getCurrentUser().then(function(data) {
            var names = JSON.stringify(data.data.display_name);
            console.log(names)
            return names;
        })
    }
}
```

The above answered why you were getting `undefined` when calling `getUser()`, but if you want to work with the end result you also want to change how you're using the value you get from getUser - it returns a promise object, not the end result you're after, so your code wants to call the promise's `then` method when the promise gets resolved:

```
getUser()                        // this returns a promise...
   .then(function(names) {       // `names` is the value resolved by the promise...
      $scope.names = names;      // and you can now add it to your $scope
   });
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new in this, It worked but I get a object that starts with $$state how do I access the data it contains?

Comment: Could you help me with that?

Comment: I added some code to handle the promise you get from `getUsers()` - I think that is a lot cleaner than the other answer I linked to in a comment earlier.

Comment: So the function inside `then` will return a value that will then be returned by `getUser`?

Comment: @Melab yes - `getUser()` returns a promise. You can access its final resolved value in the `then` function of that promise

Answer (score 0):

If you use it like that you can use the *await* call

```js
function getUser() {

    if ( $localStorage.token == undefined) {
        throw alert("Not logged in");
    }
    else {
        return Spotify.getCurrentUser().then(function(data) {
            var names = JSON.stringify(data.data.display_name);
            console.log(names)
            return names;
        });
    }
}

const names = await getUser();
```

Comment: Can we use await without adding async in function deceleration :?

Comment: No, you can't use await without async, If you will try to use you will get an error for the same.

Comment: @SaeedAnsari Yes, of course. `await` works with Promises. `async` simply exposes a Promise as the return value. If you already return a Promise then you can `await` it without `async`